# how to feed values to labels in chart.js from controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, chart.js

Currently, I am trying to populate the label values of chart.js from controller. But somehow it is not accepting the value from controller.

**My controller code looks something like this:**

```
       public ActionResult LineChart()
        {
            StringBuilder label = new StringBuilder();
            label.Append("['januar', 'februar', 'märz', 'April', 'Mai', 'Juni', 'Juli', 'August', 
                           'September', 'Oktober', 'November', 'Dezember']");
            ViewBag.Xaxis = label;
            return View();
        }
```

**My javascript code in Html:**

```
<script>
        var LineChartData =
        {           
                labels: @ViewBag.Xaxis,
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Line',
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
                    borderWidth: 2,
                    data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 5, 2, 1]
                }]
        };
</script>
```

The data in the viewbag is in the correct format required for labels, but still it is not accepting it.

How can i make **labels** to accept the **viewbag data**? Is there any other way to get data for labels from controller?

Comment: Press F12. What does the Console say? any errors perhaps? What is written in the HTML? Or maybe `ViewBag.Xaxis = label.ToString()`?

Comment: I have already tried with ToString(), it is no working. When I press F12, I can see an error in console where the labels value look like this    ** labels: [&#39;januar&#39;, &#39;februar&#39;, &#39;m&#228;rz&#39;, &#39;April&#39;, &#39;M&#228;i&#39;, &#39;Juni&#39;, &#39;Juli&#39;, &#39;August&#39;, &#39;September&#39;, &#39;Oktober&#39;, &#39;November&#39;, &#39;Dezember&#39;],**

Comment: Try `labels: @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Xaxis)`

Comment: @VDWWD The above solution worked for me. Thank you so much.